# Share a Facebook app ID across apps Android

Tags: android, facebook

[This page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/) of the Facebook iOS SDK explains how to have a single Facebook app ID shared across multiple iOS apps. However I am unable to find the same documentation in the Android area of the Facebook Developer site. Has anybody else had experience doing this or is it simply not available in Android?

Answer (score 9):

Easier than iOS,
You can use one Facebook app ID in multiple Android apps.

check [this link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#faq_105681056526435)

and I quote :

> Share app ID across Apps
>
> You can use one Facebook app ID in multiple Android apps. Just use the
>   same app ID in another app for login, sharing, and so on.
>
> For deep linking and opening your app through notifications and other
>   means, we only support a single package name/class name combination.
>
> If you want multi-app support for deep linking, see App Links.

Comment: Anyone try this and successfully implement it? I have two app (with different package name and different Main Activity class name of course), the setting in Facebook only allow me to insert one package name. My second app that share the same Facebook App ID don't have to be listed there??

Comment: @Terrence were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Terrence Following up I'm also facing this problem