# Android - Share Facebook App Id Across mulitiple Apps?

Tags: android, facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/

Currently there is documentation on how to do this with iOS, however is there a way to do this with android too?

Other SO's that may have been figured out however remain un-answered/un-responsive..

- [Facebook & iOS: Share an app ID across multiple apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498888/share-a-facebook-app-id-across-apps-android)