# One facebook app for multiple android apps

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-apps, prime31

i know this question looks like been asked several times.
But there aint a clarity of answer .

[Share a Facebook app ID across apps Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498888/share-a-facebook-app-id-across-apps-android)

My requirement is i already have a app with the bundle id [com.mycompanyname.app1]
Im going to push a lite version of the same app by the name com.mycompanyname.app2]
I already have a facebook app for app1.
i don want to create another fb app for app2 as it would divide the user access.

If this is doable let me know how i can do it ?
Thank you guys

Comment: benito , sadly yes....

Comment: Yes, it's possible, as long as you don't need deep link support for your apps (currently it will only deep link into the app that you've specified the package name for).

Comment: Thank you for replying Ming Li ..Do you mean to say i need to disable the deep link option available for the facebook app in the facebook developer dashboard ? Is there anything else i should be doing ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's very simple. You just need to use the same keys and credentials that you used for your first android app in your next app. It will work. When you go to Firebase settings, you can see that you can add another android app, but authentication settings are common for both your apps. So you do not need to change anything. As mentioned in comment, app package that you specify in Facebook console, is used only for deep linking. It does not matter for authentication.