# Facebook login with cordova in multiple applications

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I have little tricky question.

I developped a cordova application which is currently in production.

I would like to add facebook login to this app, the feature is already enabled in my website and I would like that my users can use it on the iOs and Android app (and maybe windows phone) as well.

I use this plugin : https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Facebook login don't work because I haven't added iOs and Android settings, the problem is that, by choice, I deploy my app in two different form. One paid app without ads and one free with ads.

So in the end, I have One paid android app, One free android app, One paid ios app and one free ios app from the same source code.

But facebook only allow one ios and one android setting by Facebook app, and all the apps must be linked to the same facebook App for access token to be usable by all the apps, right ?

Did someone know what could I do in this situation ?

Comment: So whatsthe big deal... use same appid for both the apps...

Comment: I thinks it is not possible, facebook ask for one and only one app store ID per app. So I could add one android and one iOs but not two android and two iOs

Comment: check the two links...
For iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993996/two-ios-apps-using-the-same-facebook-app-id-is-it-possible?answertab=votes#tab-top
for Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498888/share-a-facebook-app-id-across-apps-android?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, it appears that I haven't searched with the good keywords ^^
Could you transform your comment as anwser so I can choose it ?